# Delphi 7 how to load data from an ADOQuery to a DBChart at runtime

Tags: runtime, datasource, delphi-7

Im having the following problem with Delphi 7.
I try to use a DBchart to represent some data with a line diagram from a database.
I want the data to be loaded from an ADOQuery that gets activated at runtime thought. I can do it without problem with a query that has a static SQL value, but i find problems at setting the datasource at runtime.

I try to use

```
dbchart1.series[1].datasource:=ADOQuery3;
```

After i have created series1, but i get a "list index out of bounds" error.
Am i using the wrong command? I tried several others but failed.
Anyone can give some help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with the following (after creating series1 at the DBGrid)

```
with series1 do
begin
datasource:=ADOquery;
xlabelssource:='field1';
YValues.Valuesource:='field2';
checkdatasource;
end;
```